# How to use MLeap DenseTensor in Java

Tags: java, scala, pyspark, mleap

I am using MLeap to run a Pyspark logistic regression model in a java program. Once I run the pipeline I am able to get a `DefaultLeapFrame` object with one row `Stream(Row(1.3,12,3.6,DenseTensor([D@538613b3,List(2)),1.0), ?)`.

But I am not sure how to actually inspect the DenseTensor object. When I use `getTensor(3)` on this row I get an object. I am not familiar with Scala but that seems to be how this is meant to be interacted with. In Java how can I get the values within this DenseVector?

Here is roughly what I am doing. I'm guessing using Object is not right for the type. . .

```
DefaultLeapFrame df = leapFrameSupport.select(frame2, Arrays.asList("feat1", "feat2", "feat3", "probability", "prediction"));
Tensor<Object> tensor = df.dataset().head().getTensor(3);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the MLeap documentation for the Java DSL is not so good but I was able to look over some unit tests ([link](https://github.com/combust/mleap/blob/master/mleap-runtime/src/test/scala/ml/combust/mleap/runtime/javadsl/JavaDSLSpec.java)) that pointed me to the right thing to use. In case anyone else is interested, this is what I did.

```
DefaultLeapFrame df = leapFrameSupport.select(frame, Arrays.asList("feat1", "feat2", "feat3", "probability", "prediction"));
TensorSupport tensorSupport = new TensorSupport();
List<Double> tensor_vals = tensorSupport.toArray(df.dataset().head().getTensor(3));
```